# Using WebMethod Attribute value in method body

Tags: c#, attributes, webmethod

I am trying to use an Attribute in my method body, but do not know how.

This fake code should show what I mean (only a simple sample

```
[WebMethod(MessageName = "EnrichmentXml", Description = "Locate Enrichment XML Doc")]
public XmlDocument EnrichmentXml(string xmlRequest)
{
    SaveLog(Description + " method was called.");
}
```

In my example Description is unknown.
But how to make it usable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, an attribute is used to "decorate" an item with meta-data (which *may* alter the behavior of the item). In this case, `WebMethod` only servers to notify ASP.Net that the method it's decorating is to be called as a web service method (e.g. MyWebService.asmx/EnrichmentXml). The `Description` named parameter of the `WebMethodAttribute` class's constructor corresponds to a `Description` property if the `WebMethodAttribute` class. Since the `WebMethodAttribute` is not actually instantiated inside your method, you have no access to any members of the decorating `WebMethodAttribute`.

I would suggest the following:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
    public class MyWebServiceClass {

        private const string DESCRIPTION = "Locate Enrichment XML Doc";

        [WebMethod(MessageName = "EnrichmentXml", Description = DESCRIPTION)]
        public XmlDocument EnrichmentXml(string xmlRequest)
        {
            SaveLog(DESCRIPTION + " method was called.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Of course attributes have an other function. But I would like to avoid a double declaration of variables, this leads to errors. Your suggestion is a possible solution, but not a very beautiful: I have to declare it out of scope and because I have a lot of methods I have to declare many constants.

Comment: Well, unfortunately, that's really the only way to do what you're looking to do. Now an alternative is to do something like MS does and create a string resources class called `SR` that's internal to your assembly and which would hold all the strings in one place. (You can see this by taking ILSpy to, say, System.Windows.Forms.dll.)